# Order of execution of the Future

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  folderListcall() async {
    final directory =  await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final dir = directory.path;
    final path = Directory('$dir');
    forderList = [];
    path
        .list(recursive: false, followLinks: false)
        .listen((FileSystemEntity entity) {
      final String forder = entity.path.substring(directory.path.length + 1);
      if (!forder.contains('.')) {
        forderList.add(forder);
      }
      print('one');
    });
    print("two");
  }



flutter: two
flutter: one
flutter: one
```

Why does "two" come first when I run code of Future like this ?

I want "one" to come first.

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question and include the code in text format. It makes harder to anyone to answer if your code is inside a image.

Comment: I'm sorry. 
I've never asked a question before.
I've corrected it, as you suggested.
Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Could you please add high-level requirement into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [List](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Directory/list.html) method which returns a `Stream`.

`Streams` are asynchronous (Just like `Future`'s). The [listen](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/listen.html) method it will be called for each new value on the folder, for each sub-folder and files. Just like Future, it will be run inside an Isolate which will have it's execution made separatedly in another part of Dart's execution loop.

As the documentation states:

> Use the listen callback function to process each object as it become available.

So this feature is made to obtain the files and folders *as soon* as they are available. So as soon as the files are being discovered they are passed to your method callback.

If you want the "one" to be run before the "two", you can use something like [await for](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#receiving-stream-events) structure, which awaits for all Stream itens.

Other option, which I believe is simpler, is to use another method called [listSync](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Directory/listSync.html), which as the name implies is *synchronous* and you won't have to bother with a stream or future of events:

```
folderListcall() async {
    final directory =  await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final dir = directory.path;
    final path = Directory('$dir');
    List<FileSystemEntity> forderList= path.listSync(recursive: false, followLinks: false);
    List<String> StringList= [];
    for (FileSystemEntity entity in forderList) {
       final String forder = entity.path.substring(directory.path.length + 1);
       if (!forder.contains('.')) {
            StringList.add(forder);
       } 
    }
    
  }
```

Which should have the return you desire.

Comment: Oh, my God.

Your answer is absolutely perfect.

It was really the way I wanted it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @yasu I'm glad to help. Don't forget the mark the answer as "accepted" (the check icon on the left) to help with future searchs on the website.

Answer (score 0):

```
 path
        .list(recursive: false, followLinks: false)
        .listen((FileSystemEntity entity) {
      final String forder = entity.path.substring(directory.path.length + 1);
      if (!forder.contains('.')) {
        forderList.add(forder);
      }
      print('one');
    });
```

The part of code with `print('one')` is inside a method that you are passing as a listener to method listen.

```
path.list(...).listen((...){...});
```

It will be executed only when occurs a snapshot. So it first is added as a listener and the code below is executed.

```
print('two');
```

then when occurs a snapshot the `print('one')` is executed

Comment: Your answer made me understand the concept of listen.
Thank you very much.